# Show that for $1 \leq p < \infty$ the normed linear space $\ell^p$ provided with the norm below is a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Norm: $||x||=(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{p})^\frac{1}{p}$, $x \in \ell^p$.

To show that $\ell^p$ is a Banach space I need to show that any Cauchy sequence in $\ell^p$ converges to a point also in $\ell^p$.

I have seen a suggestion that says to use that $\ell^p$ with the infinity norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ as it can be shown that the $\ell^p$ space provided with $||\cdot||_\infty$ is Banach.

I am confused about how to use this fact and where, in fact, to start.  Should I set up a Cauchy sequence in $\ell^p$ and attempt, as usual, to show that it converges in $\ell^p$?

Comment: Hi ! This is a duplicate, I have recently answer exactly this here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276470/proving-ellp-is-complete/1276508#1276508

Comment: Thank you, I thought there might be something similar I just couldn't find it!

Comment: You are welcome ! Glad to help