# A reference for completeness of $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to find a good reference for the proof that the sequence spaces $\ell^p$ are Banach spaces (for $1\leq p \leq \infty$), because I need to give the proof to some students to read. Every reference I can find, proves the more complicated case of $L^p(\mu)$, but these students do not know measure theory and I don't want them to study measures (yet).

Of course, I can write the proof myself (I have done it in class a couple of times) but I don't want to go through the hassle of typing it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See near the beginning of [**Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471504599). I also think it's in Wheeden/Zygmund's [**Measure and Integral**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824764994), as well as quite a few other real analysis texts. In fact, I believe it's even in the [Schaum's Outline for real analysis](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0070602212).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look those up.

Answer (score 0):

If you only had looked to the related topics. The question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276470/proving-ellp-is-complete?rq=1).

Comment: I see the proof there, but what I want is a reference (again, I do know the proof). I did look at the related topics, but while I find proofs and hints, I do not find a reference (preferably to a book).

Comment: I see your point. However from the students sight it might be better to get a URL where the answer is given for free than to buy an expansive book where most of the content is useless. Presumably they will download the book illegally anyway.

Comment: I suspect Ruben will simply photocopy a few pages from the best source for his purposes he can find and hand copies out to students (or make a .pdf scanned copy for students), which is something I did quite often when I taught (I no longer teach). Fair use copying laws in the U.S. allow this if it's only two or three pages, I believe. Personally, I'd just go to the library and scan through books in the real and functional analysis (and maybe topology, for metric spaces) shelves for the best fit for the students I have, and make a copy from that.

Comment: Dave and Nathanael: Indeed, a good URL where the full proof can be found would be awesome (I don't think MathStackExchange links would serve my purpose well). I am hoping the students (each one is in a different university) can get the book from their own libraries.
I found that Kreyszig's book has a neat proof. I think I'll have them try and read that. Thanks a lot!