# Cauchy sequence in lp space

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

I've been looking through proofs of $l^p$ spaces being complete. And in order to prove that the elementwise-limit sequence also belons to $l^p$, a partial sum is used.  (See for example the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276470/proving-ellp-is-complete) )

However, I do not understand why that is needed. Why can't one do the same directly with infinite sums? 
Basically, what I want to know is why is the following not okay:

---

Let $\{x^{(n)}\}_n$ be a Cauchy sequence from $l^p$, and $\epsilon >0$. And let $x^{\infty}$ be an elementwise limit (that is $x_k^{(n)} \to x_k^{\infty}$ as $n \to \infty$ for every k).

Since $\{x^{(n)}\}_n$ is Cauchy, we know that $\sum_k |x_k^n - x_k^m|^p < \epsilon^p$ for all $n,m\geq N(\epsilon)$.
Therefore  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_k |x_k^n - x_k^m|^p  =  \sum_k |x_k^\infty - x_k^m|^p < \epsilon^p$.

---

I don't understand why this would not be okay - the only reason I could think of is the existence of the limit. But we know that that limit exists, since we know about the elementwise convergence....And it's kind of the same argumentation I guess as in the case of taking this same limit on the finite sum anyway... Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a limit and an infinite sum cannot be interchanged. So you have to say $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |x_k^{n}-x_k^{m}| <\epsilon^{p}$ for each $N$ for $n,m \geq N(\epsilon)$ and take limit as $n \to \infty$ to get  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |x_k-x_k^{m}| \geq \epsilon^{p}$ for each $N$ for $m \geq N(\epsilon)$. [Note that $<$ changes to $\leq $ when you take limits]. Now let $N \to \infty$ to finish the proof.

Comment: Hm, okay... I don't quite see why they can't be exchanged - is there any nice explanation for that? And, are you maybe aware of any special circumstances when they CAN be exchanged though?

Comment: A number of  theorems Mathematical Analysis are devoted to this. There are theorems in Measure Theory which give sufficient conditions for interchange of limits and integrals or limits and infinite sums. For a simple counterexample take $a_{nm}=\frac 1 n$ for $m \leq n$ and $0$ for $m>n$. Consider $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{nm}$ and see what happens when you take the limit inside the sum. You will be amused!