# Infinite product of Banach algebra is a Banach algebra or not

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

First I am trying to show infinte product of banach spaces is banch or not. It is in the book **Functional Analysis** by *John B. Conway*. It is proposition 4.4 in chapter 3. It says that if $\{ \mathcal{H}_i. : i\in I\}$ be a collection of Banach spaces and let $\mathcal{H}=\oplus _p \mathcal{H}_i, 1 \leq p < \infty $. Then $\mathcal{H}$ is also Banach space. Where $\mathcal{H}=\oplus _p \mathcal{H}_i= \{ x\in \prod_i \mathcal{H_i}: \|x\|={[\sum_i\|x(i)\|^p]}^{\frac{1}{p}} < \infty \}$.

**My problem:**

Let $\{x_n\} \subset \mathcal{H} $ be a Cauchy sequence. Then each $\{ x_n(i) \}$ will be also a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}_i$.lets say $x_n(i)$ converges to $x(i)$ so I will get $x=\prod_i x(i)$. Now I am struggling to show $x\in \mathcal{H}$ and even if I show that I am unable to show $x_n$ converges to $x$ in this norm. If I take $p=\infty$ then I was able to show that thing but here it is problematic. Can anyone help me to arrange $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

**Now If I have all $\mathcal{H}_i$ are banach algebras how to define multiplication of $\mathcal{H}$**

Comment: You can follow the same proof used to show that $l_p$ is a Banach space. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276470/proving-ellp-is-complete

Comment: Thanks I understood the proof I hope. can you say how to give banach algbera structure to $\mathcal{H}$ here.

Comment: It is natural to define multiplication pointwise i.e. $xy=\{x(i)y(i)\}.$